# Select2 tag creation additional parameter usage

Tags: jquery, forms, express, jquery-select2

According to the Select2 [docs](https://select2.org/tagging), it's possible to pass additional parameters for tagging/tag creation. Would like to how to access them or where could this be used?

```
$('select').select2({
  createTag: function (params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      id: term,
      text: term,
      newTag: true // add additional parameters
    }
  }
});
```